# iOS Swiftui App returning to foreground reset ObservedObjects

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have this app that use ObservedObject to share data across various views.

Defining the viewmodel

```swift
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var language: String?
}
```

Now for ContentView

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var myViewModel = MyViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Home()
        .environmentObject(self.myViewModel)
    }
}
```

Here is Home()

```swift
struct Home: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var myViewModel: MyViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(self.myViewModel.language ?? "")
                .onReceive(self.myViewModel.$language, perform: { language in
                    print(language)
                })
            Button(action: {
                self.myViewModel.language = "American English"
            }, label: {
                Text("Set the language")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

`onReceive` here is used for debug purposes

clicking the button will set language to "American English" and the Text() will show the updated string.

Now put the app on background and then click the icon to call it back to foreground: despite nothing changed on the UI, myviewmodel is NIL.

To "restore" the state, I've modified ContentView to receive a "foreground notification", as suggested here
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/how-to-be-notified-when-your-swiftui-app-moves-to-the-background

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var myViewModel = MyViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Home()
        .environmentObject(self.myViewModel)
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)) { _ in
           self.myViewModel.language = "American English"
        }
    }
}
```

The debug print in Home()'s onReceive works and shows the correct string, but the one in `Text()` disappear, as if it receive the nil value and get no subsequent refresh.

Any idea?

**EDIT**
Must keep IOS 13 compatibility

Answer (score 2):

Use instead `StateObject`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var myViewModel = MyViewModel()

...
```

Comment: I'm a freaking idiot and forgot to mention that i need to maintain IOS 13 compatibility. Edited the question also. Sorry @asperi

Comment: Then create `MyViewModel()` outside of `ContentView` and inject it in, say, `AppDelegate`, whatever. Actually nobody said that ContentView is created only once, so once recreated (in your case on bring to foreground) you have new instance of `MyViewModel`.

Comment: I just battled a bit on how to set up this on scenedelegate, but this seems to be the answer. @asperi could you please add an answer (or edit this very one) in order to give you the kudos you deserve?